# User account affects screen scaling

Tags: windows, azure, scaling

I have an Azure VM with a couple of local accounts. If I use MSTSC to connect and login with account1 then all is good. If I login with account2 then the scaling is messed up and text is so small it's impossible to read. Any ideas why?

Comment: seems like a problem with your user mstsc configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your RDP settings. No need to mention to backup everything and be careful dealing with registry, right?

```
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /F

DEL /F /S /Q /A %UserProfile%\Documents\Default.rdp

DEL /F /S /Q /A %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\1bc392b8e104a00e.automaticDestinations-ms
```